# concepts return type requirement syntax two versus one template parm

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am wondering how the `std::same_as` is defined and how we use it in a concept or requirement.

Example:

```
void f1() { } 
bool f2() { return true; }

template < typename T>
void Do( T func )
{
    if constexpr ( requires { { func() } -> std::same_as<bool>; } ) 
    {   
        std::cout << "Func returns bool " << std::endl;
    }   

    if constexpr ( requires { { func() } -> std::same_as<void>; } ) 
    {   
        std::cout << "Func returns void " << std::endl;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    Do( f1 );
    Do( f2 );
}
```

That works as expected.

But if I look on the definition of [std::same_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) I find a possible implementation:

```
namespace detail {
    template< class T, class U >
    concept SameHelper = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}
 
template< class T, class U >
concept same_as = detail::SameHelper<T, U> && detail::SameHelper<U, T>;
```

And what makes me wonder is that I see two template parms `T` and `U` in that case while we only need to write one like `{ { func() } -> std::same_as<bool>; }`.

Is it some kind of *magic* that a `{ { func() } -> std::same_as<bool>; }` will be converted to `std::same_as<magic_return_type, bool>` in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `concept` is generally similar to a `constexpr inline bool` variable template. However, it does have special properties. With regard to this question, a `concept` whose first template parameter is a type is a special kind of concept: a "type concept".

In certain locations, a type concept can be used without its first template parameter. In those places, the first parameter will be deduced based on how it gets used.

In compound requirements of a `requires` expression, a type concept is what follows the `->`. [The first parameter of the concept will be filled in by the type of the expression E in the `{}`, as if by `decltype((E))`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.req.compound#1.3.2).

Comment: Can you also give a hint where to find the "The first parameter of the concept will be filled ..." ? thanks!

Comment: @Klaus: I don't know what you mean by "where to find"? Like, in the C++ standard?

Comment: Maybe a hint to the paragraph in the c++ standard  or to something on cppreference.com ? I'll give it a try to find it myself tomorrow.

Comment: @Klaus: I provided a link to the standard.