# sfinae vs concepts with non type template parms

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts, non-type-template-parameter

For academic reasons I want to implement an example which select a template if a non type template parameter fulfills a given criteria. As example I want to have a function which is only defined for odd integer numbers.

It can be done like:

```
template < int N, bool C = N%2>
struct is_odd: public std::false_type{};
template<int N > 
struct is_odd< N,true >: std::true_type{};

template < int N>
constexpr bool is_odd_v = is_odd<N>::value;

template < int N, typename T=typename std::enable_if_t<is_odd_v<N>, int> >
void Check(){ std::cout << "odd number template specialization " << std::endl; };

int main()
{
   Check<1>();
   Check<2>(); // fails, as expected, ok
}
```

I think it is much code for doing such a simple thing. Quite clear, I directly can use the modulo operation inside the `std::enable_if` but lets assume there will be a more complex check for the non type template parameter value.

***Q: Can this be done without so many steps of indirection but still having some `std::is_xxx` in use?***

BTW: If `concepts` can handle non type template parms, it can be done much simpler, but I know, not designed for it...

```
template < int N >
concept ODD = !(N % 2); 

template < ODD N >
void Check() { std::cout << "odd number template specialization " << std::endl; }
```

Bonus: Maybe someone have an idea why concepts are not made for non type template parms?

Comment: `requires` scope doesn't represents conditions, but it check if statement are compiling. So `requires { !(N % 2); }; ` doesn't do what you are expecting.

Comment: @MarekR: You are right... but still concepts can't be used for non template parms... or is there a possible trick?

Comment: As an unrelated comment, I'm pretty sure you can do `template<typename T>constexpr bool is_odd(T num) { return num % 2 };`, no need for 3 functions (c++11 and after, but you already use `constexpr`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more experimental work I found that `concepts` can be used for non type template parms. I simply did not find anything about that in the docs I read.

```
template < int I > 
concept ODD = !(I%2);

template< int N > 
requires( ODD<N> )
void Check() { std::cout << "odd number template spezialisation " << std::endl; }

template< int N > 
requires( !ODD<N> )
void Check() { std::cout << "even number template spezialisation " << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    Check<2>();
    Check<4>();
    Check<3>();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T7ebrs1ro)

Comment: "*I simply did not find anything about that in the docs I read.*" Well, yeah. A concept is a `template`, so it takes template parameters. Concepts whose first parameter is a type [can be used in special places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70205591/734069), but that's the only special case surrounding the template nature of a concept (that, and that [you cannot constrain a concept definition itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293531/734069)).

Comment: Side note, you seems to inverted odd and even

Comment: Also, it is not advised to use ODD<N> and !ODD<N>, as it is brittle to changes. You could have a default for check and a specialisation for even.